# Local RDLC Report showing '#Error' where report parameters should be displayed

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I am using an RDLC (VS2010) to render a simple shipping label to PDF on a web page (MVC3).  I have a single parameter I need to pass to the RDLC (ShipmentId).  I pass that parameter and the report renders correctly except for the textbox that is supposed to display the parameter I pass in.

The textbox on the RDLC has its value set to '=Parameters!ShipmentId.Value'.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    shipment.ShipmentId = "123TEST";

    Warning[] warnings;
    string mimeType;
    string[] streamids;
    string encoding;
    string filenameExtension;

    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.ReportPath = @"Labels\ShippingLabel.rdlc";
    report.Refresh();

    report.EnableExternalImages = true;

    ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("ShipmentId", shipment.ShipmentId, true);
    report.SetParameters(param);

    report.Refresh();

    byte[] bytes = report.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);

    return new FileContentResult(bytes, mimeType);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that ReportViewer cannot have ReportParameters when using ProcessingMode.Local.  Instead I changed my code to use a datasource instead of paramters.

```
        Warning[] warnings;
        string mimeType;
        string[] streamids;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;

        var viewer = new ReportViewer();
        viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Labels\ShippingLabel.rdlc";
        viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

        var shipLabel = new ShippingLabel { ShipmentId = shipment.ShipmentId, Barcode = GetBarcode(shipment.ShipmentId) };

        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ShippingLabel", new List<ShippingLabel> { shipLabel }));
        viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

        var bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
```